# Using pointer-to-member functions with std::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member

I'm struggling with this piece of code:

```
typedef shared_ptr<node <T>> (node<T>::*son_getter)();
    son_getter get_son[] = {&node<T>::getLeftSon, &node<T>::getRightSon};

insert = node->*get_son[index]();
```

I get a compilation error:

```
error: must use ‘.*’ or ‘->*’ to call pointer-to-member function in ‘get_son[index] (...)’, e.g. ‘(... ->* get_son[index]) (...)’
 insert = node->*get_son[index]();
```

Where `node` is `shared_ptr<node<T>>` just as `insert` is.

I've tried everything I could guess and still no idea what's going on.

Comment: Full code, please.

Comment: @SergeyA Be careful what you wish for. :)

Comment: With brackets I get "no match for operator->*". Do I really  need to overload it?

Comment: it also seems `node` is the name of both a type and an object :/

Comment: `node` is `shared_ptr<node <T>>`

Comment: @vu1p3n0x, right in code it's different but I changed it to simpler one here. I'll fix it now.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki thanks it works now. Could you explain why do I need to dereference the pointer? Is it connected with the fact it actually points to the manager and not the object itself?

Comment: @A.Budziak it's a smart pointer, not a pointer, so you can't use operator `->*` if `shared_ptr` doesn't overload it

Comment: I get it. Thanks one more time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, a function call operator `()` has a higher priority than `->*`, as such, you need to add parenthesis to enforce the desired evaluation order. Additionally, `node` is a smart pointer, while the pointer to member function refers to the type stored in that shared pointer.

Having said that, you need to use one of the below alternatives:

```
(*node.*get_son[index])();

(&*node->*get_son[index])(); // or std::addressof(*node)->*

(node.get()->*get_son[index])();
```